# Не отображается страница в uc browser

Tags: html, css

Вот страница, которая не отображается https://dandirector.github.io/thermasteel/
проблема обнаружена на android 4.2.2 в uc brouser, хотел бы отметить, что вместо верстки видно просто белый экран. В других браузерах все гуд.

Comment: у меня на андроиде 4.2 все нормально

Comment: очень странный случай, у всех все ок, но мой телефон по прежнему не реагирует

Comment: да в UC не работает

Comment: https://github.com/DanDirector/dandirector.github.io/tree/master/thermasteel